# Debugging errors in Code::Blocks while "stepping into" varibale size array declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging, codeblocks

I'm getting strange errors while debugging in Code::Blocks, and they are showing as I declare array of a non constant size. The problem involves displaying error 10 times one by one in a debugger console, and then 7 additional errors before exiting program. And they will only show when using "step into" command from debugger.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arrSize = 3; // can be anything, any value will display the same error message exactly 10 times!

    int arr[arrSize];

    // here I get exactly 10 errors from debugger console while doing "step into" command
    // and it is showing me those errors until display it 10 times (one by one), then goes further..

    cout << "program finished";
    return 0; // and seven different errors here before exiting the program
}
```

Error message from top line (when declaring array), about 10 similar error goes here..

```
Cannot open file: ../../../../../src/gcc-4.8.1/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S
At ../../../../../src/gcc-4.8.1/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S:168 (here it changes S value while displaying similar errors)

[debug]> info locals
[debug]No locals.
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> info args
[debug]No symbol table info available.
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> bt 30
[debug]#0  __chkstk_ms () at ../../../../../src/gcc-4.8.1/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S:168
[debug]#1  0x004013c1 in main () at C:\Users\******\Desktop\seepp\aaa\main.cpp:8
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
```

Comment: `int arr[arrSize];` is a variable length array and are not standard.  I would suggest you use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) change it to `std::vector<int> arr(arrSize);`